# Dynamically and constantly push data from Flask to the web browser (i.e. print statements or flash messages)

Tags: ajax, flask

I am sending input data from a web page via AJAX request to a Flask app. During the time my Flask app processes this data I want to notify a user about what is going on. If it were a console script I would just `print()` this messages out, ie:

```
Parsing file A ...
Parsing file B ...
```

But how to dynamically push data from Flask to the web browser not causing page reloading and initiate this process from the server side?
I believe I cant use json as a response to an AJAX call since this response is done once and I want to pass the notifying messages on their time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problems: [Flask Streaming](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/streaming/)

Your route should look something like this:

```
from flask import stream_with_context, request, Response
from werkzeug import secure_filename

@app.route('/post_files')
def parse_files():
    def generate():
        for file in request.files['file']:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            yield 'Parsing file ' + filename + ' ...\n'
            parse_file(file) #your external parsing method
    return Response(stream_with_context(generate()))
```

Comment: Thanks, Snuggert. And in this case how to constantly populate a text-area or div with this approach?
I saw examples for Server Send Events and send_template, but none of them were about simple `stream_with_context` or pure `Response`